# Receiving syntax error message when trying to start application server for first Rails application after configuration [noob]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, learn-ruby-on-rails

The following message pops up when I enter $ rails server in the Terminal (Mac, running latest version of Yosemite). I'm pretty lost, other topics have recommended altering the text in the config folder of my project, but what I've tried hasn't worked and I'm guessing because those are slightly dated topics.

I'm learning from the [Learn Ruby on Rails](http://learn-rails.com/learn-ruby-on-rails.html) book trying to get this MailChimp application working, completed up to the 13th chapter without any big issues. Any help is appreciated.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.1.1 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Notice: server is listening on all interfaces (0.0.0.0). Consider using 127.0.0.1 (--     binding option)
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse':     (<unknown>): found character that cannot start any token while scanning for the next token     at line 14 column 1 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:313:in `secrets'
from /Users/dengel29/workspace/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/railtie.rb:210:in `configure'
from /Users/dengel29/workspace/learn-rails/config/environments/development.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:594:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `each'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:593:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:226:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:348:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:418:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:427:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:417:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `call'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:411:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:347:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `call'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:345:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:224:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:288:in `initialize!'
from /Users/dengel29/workspace/learn-rails/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
from /Users/dengel29/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
from /Users/dengel29/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `new'
from /Users/dengel29/workspace/learn-rails/config.ru:in `<main>'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:277:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:199:in `app'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:50:in `app'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:130:in `log_to_stdout'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:67:in `start'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:81:in `block in server'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `tap'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:76:in `server'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dengel29/workspace/learn-rails/bin/rails:8:in `require'
from /Users/dengel29/workspace/learn-rails/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `load'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:27:in `call'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/client.rb:26:in `run'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/bin/spring:48:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
from /Users/dengel29/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/spring-1.1.3/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/dengel29/workspace/learn-rails/bin/spring:16:in `require'
from /Users/dengel29/workspace/learn-rails/bin/spring:16:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `load'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: You have a syntax error in a YAML file, probably secrets.yml

Comment: What is in `config/environments/development.rb:32`?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I don't know, I don't believe I modified that file. I'm doing this from a textbook and have just been following directions. Tried to put the code here but it's too long. Any red flags I should look for?

Comment: @FrederickCheung I'll take a look at that right now, thanks I'll tell you if that resolves it.

Comment: Just show me line 32, or whole block if it's part of a block. BTW I'm surprised that everyone doing Hartl report long config files when mine are usually quite short.

Comment: This answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23036246/issues-using-config-secrets-yml-variable-set-from-env-variable-on-rails-4-1-0

Comment: @MichalSzyndel here's that code.

'config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  domain: Rails.application.secrets.domain_name,
  authentication: "plain",
  enable_starttls_auto: true,
  user_name: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_username,
  password: Rails.application.secrets.email_provider_password
}'

Comment: It's quite certain that you have a syntax error in secrets.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your ENV variables are not set up correctly, or you have an unusual character in one of the variables. Be careful there are not tab characters or any unusual characters in the *config/secrets.yml* file.

I suggest you replace all ENV values in the *config/secrets.yml* with hardcoded strings. Don't check the file into git with your private credentials in the file. Just test it to see if you can isolate the problem.

Comment: I tried hardcoding it but I keep receiving a similar error. I checked to make sure everything was entered correctly in my bash_profile files (there's one located in my workspace and another in my home directory, I guess I created two, not sure which I need).

I'm searching for tab characters (they have ampersands, correct?) and other errors, but I'm really struggling to get past this point. Looking at bash_profile, secrets,yml, and config/environments/development to solve but haven't found anything that differs from the code you offered in the book. Looking for any alternatives

Comment: I notice you said you are using a Mac running the latest version of Yosemite. I doubt that is the cause of this problem, but you should use OS X Mavericks (10.9.4 is current) right now, since Yosemite is still in beta. It's difficult to help you when you are using a beta version of the Mac OS.

Comment: Your problem should go away when you replace all ENV values in the *config/secrets.yml* with hardcoded strings. You may need to enter `$ bin/spring stop` after changing the *config/secrets.yml* file. Check if Rails is running its cached version with `$ bin/spring status`.

Comment: Rewrote everything in the secrets.yml file, now we're rolling! Thanks for bearing with me! Appreciate all your help and writing the textbook and all that. Hoping I can persevere through the rest of it!

Comment: Glad you are making progress. Please check the checkmark to accept the answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow.